# What are the alternatives to this JavaScript function that increase/decrease a number?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I want to find alternatives to this function that are written with less line of code.

This is mine:

```
<div onclick="operation('increase')"></div>
<div onclick="operation('decrease')"></div>

number = 0;

operation(op){

    if(op === 'increase'){
        this.number += 1;
    }

    if(op === 'decrease'){
        this.number -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: "better" how? By which metric?

Comment: Define "better". You could use a `switch` but I don't know if that would make it "better".

Comment: [codereview.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using a number directly?

```
<div (click)="operation(1)"></div>
<div (click)="operation(-1)"></div>

value = 0;

operation(op){

    this.value += op;
}
```

Comment: How is that "better"?

Comment: @RobG in the context of the title. It avoids the string comparison.

Comment: so tough people.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you mean with 'better' but here are some alternative solutions:

```
<div (click)="operation('increase')"></div>
<div (click)="operation('decrease')"></div>

value = 0;

operation(op){
    if(op === 'increase') this.value++;
    if(op === 'decrease') this.value--;
}
```

or

```
<div (click)="operation(1)"></div>
<div (click)="operation(-1)"></div>

value = 0;

operation(op){
    this.value += op;
}
```